# How to set an icon at the end of Toolbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I want to set an icon at the the end of my `Toolbar`,which start another activity.
My `Toolbar` portion

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
                android:background="#2B4AE0"
                app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/headerText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Theme"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/notification"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"

                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/bell_icon" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I tried

```
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
```

and setting margin left but it doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try adding this to your ImageView:

```
android:layout_gravity="end"
```

Comment: @Sam Works. But when you have items in your `menu_main` file then this `ImageView` would be placed to the left of those items. How would you put the `ImageView` always to the right side (no matter if there are menu items or not)?

Answer (score 19):

If you want something like this (icon 2)
[image: example]

You do not need add icon to the layout manually, you should to implement [menu.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

1. Create menu.xml like this

   > ```
   > <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   > <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   >     <item android:id="@+id/new_activity"
   >         android:icon="@drawable/ic_custom_icon"
   >         android:title="@string/new_activity" />
   > </menu>
   > ```
2. Add it in your activity/fragment to the actionbar/toolbar by

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
      return true;
   }
   ```
3. Handle menu items events

Toolbar with menus works fine, it sets icons to the right of toolbar automatically

Comment: What if I want to add a custom icon

Comment: @android_sh_jo add android:icon="@drawable/ic_your_custom_icon"  to menu xml, updated code in answer

Comment: this will not work if he doesn't want to use supportactionbar

Answer (score 8):

If there's anyone that still confused (including me before), somehow android studio doesn't provide autocomplete for the `android:layout_gravity` under the `toolbar` tag. So to make it works, just copy and paste `android:layout_gravity="end"` to the `ImageView`/layout.

Answer (score 3):

Setting the orderInCategory will set the order of the menu item

```
 <item 
    ...
      android:orderInCategory="150"
      app:showAsAction="always"
    ..
    />
```

if you want to put margin between your menu items you can add an empty menu item in between

Answer (score 2):

```
<item
    android:title="kjljk"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:id="@+id/menuitem_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/pdficon"
    >
</item>
```

Then in OnCreateView:
 setHasOptionsMenu(true);
Closing the OncreateView below write this:
 @Override

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.pdf, menu);
    ...
}
```

Comment: If you are using navigation toolbar then this is the proper way to add icon