# Item Menu with a color as background using Toolbar

Tags: android, menu, toolbar, menuitem

I am using Toolbar from the support AppCompat v21 library and I want to put a color as background in a Item.

[I want something like this (Image link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsrDO.png)

I can't put the background with the full height of the Toolbar

[I am getting this (Image link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1V8d.png)

My code:
menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:xxxx="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/new_action_search"
        android:title="@string/buscador_hint_busqueda"
        xxxx:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        xxxx:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search_filter"
        android:title="@string/buscador_filtrar"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_filter"
        xxxx:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_save"
        android:title="@string/buscador_save"
        android:icon="@drawable/action_item_save_icon"
        xxxx:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

action_item_save_icon.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/green_bumeran_material"></solid>
            <size
                android:height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:width="?attr/actionBarSize" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_pin_save" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use views into toolbar instead of menu, make your own layout

[look to this question, he use layout instead of menus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27923944/set-icon-at-the-end-of-toolbar)

Answer (score 0):

Create an xml layout with your desired look. Make sure the height="match_parent". Get a hold of your menu, then get the appropriate item with [`menu.getItem(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#getItem(int)). Then on your `MenuItem` do [`menuItem.setActionView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setActionView(int)) with either an inflated layout or the resource id for that layout.